# Cannot SSH to localhost without password

Tags: linux, ssh, centos, centos-6

First off, I want to say that I've tried everything in this question here, and it didn't help me: [How to SSH to localhost without password?](https://superuser.com/questions/336226/how-to-ssh-to-localhost-without-password)

I had a file permissions issue recently because I don't know how to Linux in which I typed `chmod 700 -R /home`, because I am a dumb. That might have something to do with my problem today. Someone helped me to fix that issue, but I thought I would bring it up because SSH is so stubborn about file permissions.

Here is SSH's verbose output log:

```
[user@centos ~]$ ssh -v localhost
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to localhost [::1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/identity-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'localhost' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:7
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_500' not found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_500' not found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information


debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_500' not found

debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Offering public key: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
user@localhost's password:
```

Here are the file permissions for the .ssh directory as well as its contents:

```
drwx------.  2 user user     4096 Jul  7 08:52 .ssh

drwx------.  2 user user 4096 Jul  7 08:52 .
drwxrwxr-x. 44 user user 4096 Jul  7 08:43 ..
-rw-------   1 user user 2183 Jul  7 08:52 authorized_keys
-rw-------   1 user user  672 Jul  7 08:52 id_dsa
-rw-r--r--   1 user user  603 Jul  7 08:52 id_dsa.pub
-rw-------.  1 user user 1675 Jul  2 10:55 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--.  1 user user  395 Jul  2 10:55 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r--   1 user user 2733 Jul  2 10:45 known_hosts
```

EDIT: Someone asked for the contents of /var/log/secure, so here they are. I removed my username, as it is my real name.

```
Jul  7 08:53:21 centos sshd[2611]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user *USERNAME REMOVED* by (uid=0)
Jul  7 08:55:25 centos sshd[2648]: Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /home/*USERNAME REMOVED*
Jul  7 08:55:25 centos sshd[2648]: Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /home/*USERNAME REMOVED*
Jul  7 08:56:59 centos sshd[2649]: Connection closed by ::1
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

You get the following error:

> Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /home/*USERNAME REMOVED*

That would seem to imply (if you have left out **only** your user name) that you have the wrong permissions on your $HOME directory. On  my system, I have:

```
  $ ls -lhd .
    drwxr-xr-x 104 myname myname 4.0K Jul  7 5:14 .
```

Do you have anything different?

Incidentally, the  *client* log is pretty nigh useless, you should use the *server* log, since this is your very own pc. The easiest way is to stop the running ssh server, then issue, as sudo,

```
  # /usr/sbin/sshd -dD
```

which prevents ssh from daemonizing, and also increases the output to the *debug* level. Now, from a different terminal, try to ssh into localhost,

```
  $ ssh myname@localhost
```

and see the error messages appearing in the `sshd` terminal. That should help you, possibly more.